# javascript encodeURIcomponent, when to use and browsers

Tags: google-chrome, console, mode, strict, encodeuricomponent

1. Should I use encodeURIcomponent to pass datetime strings to the servers? I've noticed it worked even without. the datetime string format I pass to server is 11/08/2014 18:15 for example. As you see, there is a space, so I'm unsure if it will be good to use it or not?
2. I've noticed that chrome(my dev browser) will usually do the encoding for me, which is good and bad. The bad part is that I do not notice my errors. I pass non-ASCII characters to the server, and in chrome and Firefox it worked fine, but in IE it does not. I've spent hours to find why this is happening till I found. So the question here is how to make chrome more "strict"? and it does not refer only to this, but also to other errors that chrome does not show any error in console. For example, chrome will usually 'smooth' HTML markup errors, which is good for production, but bad for development. So, how to make it more strict?

Comment: *How* are you passing the query data? POST/GET Form/Ajax/Using a library?

Comment: AJAX POST using jQuery. Is that matters?

Answer (score 0):

Your using jQuery so it depends what you pass to `$.post`'s `data` property.

If you pass an object `.post` will take care of encoding for you.

If you pass a `form.serialize()` then that method has already encoded it for you.

If you pass a string then you need to encode it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I pass a string. I'll encode it. Now I'm still looking for answer for the second question.